# IntelliJ IDEA and specifying GIT refspecs

Tags: git, intellij-idea, refspec

I've been using Eclipse with GIT and Gerrit for a long time but decided to give  community edition of IntelliJ IDEA (12.1.3) a try. I'm able to fetch and pull changes from our repository but I can't find an option in IntelliJ where I can specify refspecs for push operations. Is there a way to do this within IntelliJ?

Comment: Do you want to be able to specify an absolutely custom refspec or, for instance, just the target branch?

Comment: I need to do something like, from refs/heads/master to refs/for/master

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git Push from IDEA pushes only the current branch, and I don't think it will change in future. 
However, you may specify the target branch in the text field below the commits to be pushed.
There is a couple of problems with usability like [IDEA-98693](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-98693), but hopefully they will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking too much inside the box and it didn't occur to me that I could actually add refspecs inside this box.

Answer (score 0):

In PUSH dialog choose option "Push current branch to alternative branch", choose remote repository and type /refs/for/'branch' in text fields. It works in IDEA 13.0.2

Answer (score 0):

When using IntelliJ together with Gerrit, you could use the intellij-gerrit-plugin. It also has Gerrit specific push support (refs/for target branch).

http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7272